# Difference quotient in little-$o$ notation

Tags: calculus, notation

I understand that, in the following definition of the derivative, 
$$f'(x_0)=\frac{f(x_0+\delta x)-f(x_0)}{\delta x}+\frac{o(\delta x)}{\delta x},$$
The term $o(\delta x)$ denotes a remainder.
And that $f(x)=o(g(x))$ implies that $$\lim_{x \to x_0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0.$$
However, I cannot reconcile the two facts. My question being: how is the application of $o$ notation in the definition of the derivative related to the implication of it in its own definition?

Does it simply represent a value smaller than $\delta x$ for $x \to 0$?

It is presented as though it ought to be rather obvious, and likely it is, but still some aspect of it escapes my comprehension.

Comment: This notation is a general notation which is used outside of the definition of the derivative. it means that "even after" dividing by $g(x)$, $f(x)$ goes to zero. This tells us that when approaching the limit point, the function which is defined by the derivative, gets closer to the limit "faster" than the $\delta x$ function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard definition of the derivative is
$$
f'(x)=\lim_{\delta x\to0}\frac{f(x+\delta x)-f(x)}{\delta x}\tag{1}
$$
Now, $\frac{o(\delta x)}{\delta x}=o(1)$, which is any function that vanishes as $\delta x\to0$. An advantage of the notation $\frac{o(\delta x)}{\delta x}$ is that it mentions $\delta x$, which $o(1)$ does not.  In any case, your equation is the same as
$$
f'(x)=\frac{f(x+\delta x)-f(x)}{\delta x}+o(1)\tag{2}
$$
simply means that as $\delta x\to0$, the fraction on the right side of $(2)$ tends to the left side of $(2)$. This is exactly what $(1)$ says.

Comment: How are $\frac{o(\delta x)}{\delta x}$ and $o(1)$ equivalent? I don't imagine that it's as simple as a division. Unless it is.

Comment: $o(\delta x)$ is any function of $\delta x$, say $f(\delta x)$, so that $\lim\limits_{\delta x\to0}\frac{f(\delta x)}{\delta x}=0$. $\frac{o(\delta x)}{\delta x}$ such a function divided by $\delta x$; e.g. $\frac{f(x)}{\delta x}$, and we've just said that this tends to $0$ as $\delta x\to0$. Thus, $\frac{f(x)}{\delta x}=o(1)$.

Comment: Ah! I had presumed from the definition i.e. $f(x)=o(g(x))$ that the argument of $o$ must be a function--hence my confusion, being that I could not extrapolate from $o(\delta x)$ to the left side, which was in actuality any function of $\delta x$.

Comment: @McTigue: You were not really mistaken since $x$ *is* a function of $x$; this means that $o(x)$ represents any function, say $f(x)$, so that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}x=0$.

Comment: @McTigue $1$ is a function!